JSONForms: Display multiple fields as one string
I am creating a custom renderer to display a JSON form as an overview of the data saved in other json forms.
Most fields have to be displayed just with a single title and value from the database.
Some fields though have to be merged and displayed as a single string with commas, for example the address has to be displayed in this format:
Street, nr.
Main Street, 15
and
Zip code, city
9011, London
EDIT
my JSON schema is
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Overview",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
    "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "location": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "address": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "street": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Street"
                },
                "house_number": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "nr."
                },
                "city": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "City"
                },
                "zip": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Zip code"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


and my uischema is
{
      "type": "Group",
      "label": "Location",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "HorizontalLayout",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "Overview",
              "scope": "#/properties/data/properties/location/properties/address/properties/street"
            },
            {
              "type": "Overview",
              "scope": "#/properties/data/properties/location/properties/address/properties/house_number"
            },
            {
              "type": "Overview",
              "scope": "#/properties/data/properties/location/properties/address/properties/city"
            },
            {
              "type": "Overview",
              "scope": "#/properties/data/properties/location/properties/address/properties/zip"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
...

Is there a way to merge many elements (titles and values) and display them as a single string?
Can I do it in my custom renderer or do I need a custom layout for this case?
Thank you in advance!

You need to provide the JSON to get a decent answer.

@GetOffMyLawn sure, I updated the question qith some JSON.

I came up with a solution for this using the renderer for "ListWithDetail" from https://github.dev/eclipsesource/jsonforms as an example.
In the ui-schema I use options with labelRefs:
{
          "type": "Overview",
          "scope": "#/properties/data/properties/location/properties/address",
          "options": {
            "labelRefs": [
              "#/properties/street",
              "#/properties/house_number"
            ]
          }
        }

In the renderer then:
const labelRefInstancePaths = this.uischema.options.labelRefs.map((path) => removeSchemaKeywords(path));

this.label = labelRefInstancePaths
  .map((path) => this.scopedSchema.properties[path].title)
  .filter(Check.isDefined)
  .join(', ');
this.displayedValue = labelRefInstancePaths
  .map((path) => this.data[path])
  .filter(Check.isDefined)
  .join(', ');

